# Using a comparator and a separate compareTo method for a PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator, compareto

If I have a PriorityQueue made up of T objects, and T has a compareTo() method and implements comparable, but my PriorityQueue also takes a comparator as a parameter, what is my PriorityQueue going to look to for the ordering of its elements?

In other words, which one determines the priority of the objects? The compareTo() method or the provided comparator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the `comparator` parameter of the constructor states that

> `comparator` - the comparator used to order this priority queue. If null then the order depends on the elements' natural ordering.

This means that when a `comparator` is specified, the natural ordering established by the `compareTo` method is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

For a standard PriorityQueue, if you construct it with the `Comparator<T>`, then that will determine the priority. If not, then the `Comparable<T>` will determine it. This is all well described in the [PriorityQueue API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! Any insight as to WHY it works that way? Is this part of a bigger Java picture?

Comment: @nobillygreen: Why would you expect something different?  This behavior seems pretty intuitive to me.

Comment: @nobillygreen: because that is how its defined in the API.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading through the [source code for Oracle's implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.java.html) of the `PriorityQueue` class and it checks if a Comparator is being used and uses that first.  Otherwise, it uses the Comparable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable defines the natural ordering of a class within a collection while a Comparator allows you to provide a different ordering. If you decide to provide the different Comparator it will override the natural order. By not entering a comparator, it will revert to the natural order set by the compareTo method.